# PLSQL OOP vs. Procedural

Tags: oracle, oop, plsql

Is there any performance difference between PLSQL OOP vs. PLSQL Procedural programing?
I am thinking that there is no difference, but maybe I am wrong.

Thanks,
Mikcutu.

Comment: You may write comparably good/bad code for both approaches. The most of performance is achieved by optimal code, not an approach to compose this code.

Comment: In my opinion the Oracle PL/SQL OOP is more like a "we must follow the hype". The OOP related functions are rather limited and potentially it still has many undiscovered bugs. For me the most important reason to avoid it is that it is hardly used and if you like to get support or google for examples then the outcome is fairly low. When you search for "plsql oop" on SO, then you get maybe 3 questions per year! Don't get me wrong, there are reason to use PL/SQL OOP from time to time, but better you should not exaggerate it. You may become a well known user in the Oracle Support organization.

Comment: What Wernfried said. OOP is Oracle trying to say "we can do it too!" on an industry fad. They do that a lot. You're better off sticking with their core product. PL/SQL is fast enough for most purposes and being procedural is easy to understand. You can ensure it is natively compiled rather than interpreted to speed it up more. But for most apps, 90%+ of their runtime is typically SQL, not PL/SQL.